# Python table comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

Is there any way to compare to printed tables at the same time printing for the same for loop? Can petl be used for such logics?.

What I exactly mean

```
loop = 2
up = 3
down = 4
listvar = [5, 6, 5, 8, 9, 7, 8, 5, 6]

docuvar = docx.Document()

for x in range(loop):
    tablevar = docuvar.add_table(rows=5, cols=5)
    for cell in (tablevar.rows[1].cells):
        for x in range(down):
            randomvar = random.choices(listvar)
        cell.text = str(randomvar)
```

Is there any way we can compare and control the integers printing or strings printing in each cell in the real time?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you elaborate it a little more? Please, check ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips on that article.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me. Which variables do you want to compare? What do you mean by control? As far as I understand - and as loops are basically sequential - you want to know if a sequence was already printed? By appending your choices to new lists you can compare before printing.

Comment: @accdias I'm sorry, I updated the question. This might not be pure python code but I couldn't come up with a code to make a perfect example and anyway I'm working with python-docx so might as well solve that problem.

Comment: @user2853437 thanks. I can try that.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure, what you exactly want to compare but here is an example how you could compare values:

```
loop = 2
up = 3
down = 4
listvar = [5, 6, 5, 8, 9, 7, 8, 5, 6]

docuvar = docx.Document()

completeList = []

for x in range(loop):
    anotherList = []
    tablevar = docuvar.add_table(rows=5, cols=5)
    for cell in (tablevar.rows[1].cells):
        #** This loop her makes no sense, except:**
        for x in range(down):
            randomvar = random.choices(listvar)
        #** you intend cell.text**
            cell.text = str(randomvar)

            #eg comparing:
            if completeList:
                for list in completeList:
                    if list[x] == str(randomvar):
                        #control smth...
                        pass

            anotherList.append(str(randomvar))
    completeList.append(anotherList)
```